# How can I access Route._loadedRoutes for Lay Loaded routes

Tags: angular

Is there a way to expose Route._loadedRoutes when looking at the routes that get loaded lazily? I am trying to create an array of the route paths, normally looping through the children the information is available. However I cant seem to find a way to access Route._loadedRoutes without casting as an any.

Looking through the Angular Route code it seems to be declared as an internal property only.

Is there a better solution than this?

```
 this.router.events
  .pipe(filter(event => event instanceof RouteConfigLoadEnd))
  .subscribe((event: RouteConfigLoadEnd) => {
    if ((event?.route as any)?._loadedRoutes) {
      const loadedRoutes: Routes = (event?.route as any)?._loadedRoutes;
    }
  });
```

Comment: Can you provide more details on the use case? What problem are you trying to solve by accessing this private property? Maybe there's a better way to do it.

Comment: I am trying to get the routes that were lazy loaded, so I can access the route properties for path and title. The router lets you parse through the declared routes by exposing the config property, that exposes an array of Routes, I would like to see those routes for lazy loaded routes